# Firebase App Check prevents Firestore unlimited requests?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

I know that firestore cannot set the rate limit separately. (prevent same firestore repeat requests)

Is it possible if I use "App Check"?

It seems there is no question about this.. so I ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase App Check does not enforce any rate limiting. It just provides attestation of app or device authenticity. If you enforce App Check, any unverified requests (without App Check token or with an invalid token) will be rejected.

Checkout [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fjj4fmr2t04) to learn more about App Check.

Comment: Hi do you know how to prevent tons of requests? (like d-dos?) that comes to firestore?